# TypeError: withColumn() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: apache, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to create 2 columns in Databricks which are the result of substractin the values of 2 columns and adding the values of these 2 colums.

This is the code I've entered.

```
dfPrep = dfCleanYear.withColumn(df.withColumn("NuevaCol", df["AverageTemperature"] - df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"])).withColumn(df.withColumn("NuevaCol", df["AverageTemperature"] + df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"]))
dfPrep.show()
```

And this the error.

TypeError: withColumn() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Would you know which argument is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which Spark version/flavour you're using. But DataBricks documentation is usually clear about this, first parameter in `.withColumn` call should be a DataFrame.

Example: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/1.6/sparkr/functions/withColumn.html

> **Syntax:**
>
> withColumn(df, “newColName”, colExpr)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> df: Any SparkR DataFrame
>
> newColName: String, name of new column to be added
>
> colExpr: Column Expression

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite your code:

```
a = df.withColumn("NuevaCol", df["AverageTemperature"] - df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"]) 
b = df.withColumn("NuevaCol", df["AverageTemperature"] + df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"])
dfPrep = dfCleanYear.withColumn(a).withColumn(b)
```

The first two lines are fine. The error comes from the 3rd one. There are two problems with this line:

- The `withColumn` syntax should be `dataframe.withColumn("New_col_name", expression)`, here there is only one argument in the brackets
- What you want here is to take a column from one dataframe `df` and add to another dataframe `dfCleanYear`. So, you should use `join`, not `withColumn`.

Something likes (not tested):

```
df = df.withColumn("NuevaCol_A", df["AverageTemperature"] - df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"]) 
df = df.withColumn("NuevaCol_B", df["AverageTemperature"] + df["AverageTemperatureUncertainty"])
dfPrep = dfCleanYear.join(df, "KEY")
```